# build schema for specific tables in database using doctrine?

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4

In my **symfony** project i need to generate schema from specific tables not all database tables ,so please tell the way to do if it is possible?

Comment: You can generate the schema for all tables and delete the parts you don't need. As far as I know there is no option to generate the schema at a "per table" basis.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the command build-schema you can generate a schema from the database that is configured for the project. The schema.yml in the config folder should contain all the tables, and you can delete the tables you do not need, and then use the commands build-model, build-form, and build-filters in order to create the classes for the remaining tables. This way, there will only be classes for the tables that you want.
Hope this helps!